# How can I troubleshoot pod stuck at ContainerCreating

Tags: kubernetes, kata-containers

I'm trying to troubleshoot a failing pod but I cannot gather enough info to do so.  Hoping someone can assist.

[server-001 ~]$ kubectl get pods sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d-26ljd

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d-26ljd   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          18m
```

[server-001 ~]$ kubectl logs sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d-26ljd

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container "nginx-kata" in pod "sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d-26ljd" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
```

[server-001 ~]$ kubectl describe pods sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d-26ljd

```
Name:           sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d-26ljd
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           worker-001/100.100.230.34
Start Time:     Fri, 08 Jul 2022 09:41:08 +0000
Labels:         name=sandboxed-nginx
                pod-template-hash=98bb68c4d
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d
Containers:
  nginx-kata:
    Container ID:
    Image:          dummy-registry.com/test/nginx:1.17.7
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-887n4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-887n4:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple     sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age    From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               25m    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/sandboxed-nginx-98bb68c4d-26ljd to worker-001
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  5m19s  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

[worker-001 ~]$ sudo crictl images

```
IMAGE                                                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
dummy-registry.com/test/externalip-webhook   v1.0.0-1            e2e778d82e6c3       147MB
dummy-registry.com/test/flannel              v0.14.1             52e470e10ebf9       209MB
dummy-registry.com/test/kube-proxy           v1.22.8             93ab9e5f0c4d6       869MB
dummy-registry.com/test/nginx                1.17.7              db634ca7e0456       310MB
dummy-registry.com/test/pause                3.5                 dabdc5fea3665       711kB
dummy-registry.com/test/linux                7-slim              41388a53234b5       140MB
```

[worker-001 ~]$ sudo crictl ps

```
CONTAINER           IMAGE                                                              CREATED             STATE               NAME                ATTEMPT             POD ID
b1c6d1bf2f09a       db634ca7e045638213d3f68661164aa5c7d5b469631bbb79a8a65040666492d5   34 minutes ago      Running             nginx               0                   3598c2c4d3e88
caaa14b395eb8       e2e778d82e6c3a8cc82cdf3083e55b084869cd5de2a762877640aff1e88659dd   48 minutes ago      Running             webhook             0                   8a9697e2af6a1
4f97ac292753c       52e470e10ebf93ea5d2aa32f5ca2ecfa3a3b2ff8d2015069618429f3bb9cda7a   48 minutes ago      Running             kube-flannel        2                   a4e4d0c14cafc
aacb3ed840065       93ab9e5f0c4d64c135c2e4593cd772733b025f53a9adb06e91fe49f500b634ab   48 minutes ago      Running             kube-proxy          2                   9e0bc036c2d00
```

[worker-001 ~]$ sudo crictl pods

```
POD ID              CREATED             STATE               NAME                                             NAMESPACE                      ATTEMPT             RUNTIME
3598c2c4d3e88       34 minutes ago      Ready               nginx-9xtss                                      default                        0                   (default)
8a9697e2af6a1       48 minutes ago      Ready               externalip-validation-webhook-7988bff847-ntv6d   externalip-validation-system   0                   (default)
9e0bc036c2d00       48 minutes ago      Ready               kube-proxy-9c7cb                                 kube-system                    0                   (default)
a4e4d0c14cafc       48 minutes ago      Ready               kube-flannel-ds-msz7w                            kube-system                    0                   (default)
```

[worker-001 ~]$ cat /etc/crio/crio.conf

```
[crio]
  [crio.image]
    pause_image = "dummy-registry.com/test/pause:3.5"
    registries = ["docker.io", "dummy-registry.com/test"]
  [crio.network]
    plugin_dirs = ["/opt/cni/bin"]
  [crio.runtime]
    cgroup_manager = "systemd"
    conmon_cgroup = "system.slice"
    conmon = "/usr/libexec/crio/conmon"
    manage_network_ns_lifecycle = true
    manage_ns_lifecycle = true
    selinux = false

  [crio.runtime.runtimes]
    [crio.runtime.runtimes.kata]
      runtime_path = "/usr/bin/containerd-shim-kata-v2"
      runtime_type = "vm"
      runtime_root = "/run/vc"

    [crio.runtime.runtimes.runc]
      runtime_path = "/usr/bin/runc"
      runtime_type = "oci"
```

[worker-001 ~]$ egrep -v '^#|^;|^$' /usr/share/defaults/kata-containers/configuration-qemu.toml

```
[hypervisor.qemu]
initrd = "/usr/share/kata-containers/kata-containers-initrd.img"
path = "/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm"
kernel = "/usr/share/kata-containers/vmlinuz.container"
machine_type = "q35"
enable_annotations = []
valid_hypervisor_paths = ["/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm"]
kernel_params = ""
firmware = ""
firmware_volume = ""
machine_accelerators=""
cpu_features="pmu=off"
default_vcpus = 1
default_maxvcpus = 0
default_bridges = 1
default_memory = 2048
disable_block_device_use = false
shared_fs = "virtio-9p"
virtio_fs_daemon = "/usr/libexec/kata-qemu/virtiofsd"
valid_virtio_fs_daemon_paths = ["/usr/libexec/kata-qemu/virtiofsd"]
virtio_fs_cache_size = 0
virtio_fs_extra_args = ["--thread-pool-size=1", "-o", "announce_submounts"]
virtio_fs_cache = "auto"
block_device_driver = "virtio-scsi"
enable_iothreads = false
enable_vhost_user_store = false
vhost_user_store_path = "/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm"
valid_vhost_user_store_paths = ["/var/run/kata-containers/vhost-user"]
valid_file_mem_backends = [""]
pflashes = []
valid_entropy_sources = ["/dev/urandom","/dev/random",""]
[factory]
[agent.kata]
kernel_modules=[]
[runtime]
internetworking_model="tcfilter"
disable_guest_seccomp=true
disable_selinux=false
sandbox_cgroup_only=true
static_sandbox_resource_mgmt=false
sandbox_bind_mounts=[]
vfio_mode="guest-kernel"
disable_guest_empty_dir=false
experimental=[]
[image]
```

[server-001 ~]$ cat nginx.yaml

```
---
kind: RuntimeClass
apiVersion: node.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kata-containers
handler: kata
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sandboxed-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: sandboxed-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: sandboxed-nginx
    spec:
      runtimeClassName: kata-containers
      containers:
        - name: nginx-kata
          image: dummy-registry.com/test/nginx:1.17.7
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sandboxed-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: sandboxed-nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx
    spec:
      tolerations:
        # this toleration is to have the daemonset runnable on master nodes
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: dummy-registry.com/test/nginx:1.17.7
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

[server-001 ~]$  kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml

```
runtimeclass.node.k8s.io/kata-containers unchanged
deployment.apps/sandboxed-nginx created
service/sandboxed-nginx created
daemonset.apps/nginx created
```

Comment: You can check kubelet and crio logs on the nodes where the pod got deployed.  journalctl -u kubelet  and journalctl -u crio It will give info of issue

Comment: journalctl for crio & kubelet returns the following:   Could not create the sandbox resource controller cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist.

Comment: Please cross verify below values crio.conf  if you want to Kata Runtime then the below values should be matching accordingly [crio.runtime.runtimes.kata]
      runtime_path = "/usr/bin/containerd-shim-kata-v2"
      runtime_type = "vm"
      runtime_root = "/run/vc"

Comment: @mickt I have a slighly different setup (rke2 and containerd on ubuntu), but same error message both with Firecracker and CloudHypervisor. Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `kata` containers with `cri-o` runtime, your pod should have a `RuntimeClass` parameter which it is missing.

You need to create a `RuntimeClass` object which will point to the runtime installed. See the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/runtime-class/) for how to do that. Also, make sure that the `cri-o` setup on `worker-001` is correctly configured with k8s. [Here](https://github.com/kata-containers/documentation/blob/master/how-to/run-kata-with-k8s.md) is documentation for that.

Afterwards, add a `RuntimeClass` parameter to your pod so that the container can actually run. The `ContainerCreating` stage is stuck since the `Pod` controller cannot run `cri-o` based containers unless the `RuntimeClass` is specified. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) is some documentation on understanding `Container Runtimes.`

Comment: (I can't seem to edit comments so that they are more presentable)  I run a test script, which has the following.

kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml

1st few lines from nginx.yaml:

    ---
    kind: RuntimeClass
    apiVersion: node.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: kata-containers
    handler: kata

Comment: I added crio.conf & nginx.yaml to main body above

Comment: And does that still not work?

Comment: Correct, it fails as outlined.